# Using the org.apache.hadoop.utilProgressable interface

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

Can someone provide an example of how the Progressable interface might be implemented for use when calling FileSystem.create()? I saw the following code snippet in another post, but it did not show where bytesWritten came from:

```
OutputStream os = hdfs.create( file,
    new Progressable() {
        public void progress() {
            out.println("...bytes written: [ "+bytesWritten+" ]");
        } });
```

The documentation of this interface says it is for reporting progress to the Hadoop framework to avoid timeout in the case of a lengthy operation, but "Hadoop: The Definitive Guide" says it is for notifying the application of the progress of the data being written to the data nodes, which doesn't make much sense since it is a create.

Thanks, RF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an implementation of `Mapper` where an invocation of `map()` may take a long time (like more than several minutes), then you can periodically call `progress()` on the provided context object to let Hadoop know that your code isn't hung. That's what they mean by "explicitly reporting progress" - it works when you're using an object provided by the framework that implements `Progressable`, it obviously doesn't work that way when you write your own implementation of `Progressable`.

Answer (score 0):

I should have read the Hadoop book further -- here is the example they gave later on:

```
            OutputStream    out =   fs.create(new   Path(dst),  new Progressable()  {
                    public  void    progress()  {
                            System.out.print(".");
                    }
```

The accompanying text says "    We  illustrate  progress
by  printing    a   period  every   time    the progress()  method  is  called  by  Hadoop, which   is  after each  64  KB  packet  of  data    is  written to  the datanode    pipeline".

I guess my question becomes, how does this "explicitly report progress to the Hadoop framework" as stated by the documentation of Progressable?